# Hive- join table with itself with inequality conditions

Tags: join, hive, left-join, hiveql, inequality

I would like to join a table with itself to find a parent of every line with an equality conditions.
Also I need to keep only one parent by taking the one who's the field "counts" is minimum.
here's a sample data:

```
product  date1           date2          version   counts
A.16    15/04/2021      17/04/2021      1         20
A.18    18/04/2021      16/04/2021      1         15
A.15    17/04/2021      18/03/2021      1         18
A.20    19/04/2021      20/03/2021      1         33
A.35    20/04/2021      30/03/2021      1          8
```

here's the request:

```
select  b.product
      , b.date1
      , b.date2
      , b.version
      , c.product as parent
from pr_convert b
left join pr_convert c
on (c.date1< b.date1 and c.date2> b.date2)
```

This did not work, it threw me this error :

`Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'date1'`

Then I tried to put the inequality condition in a where clause by doing this:

```
select  b.product
      , b.date1
      , b.date2
      , b.version
      , c.product as parent
from pr_convert b
left join pr_convert c
on b.version=c.version
where b.date1< c.date1 and b.date2> c.date2
```

As the value of the field "version" is the same for all records and my table being very large, it consumes a lot of resources and takes a lot of time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to have some key columns between b and c. This will take very long time and wont give you correct data. one row from table b will be compared with every row in table c and will generate data which can be wrong. If you share some sample data, we will be able to help you better.

Comment: thank you for your reponse, i don't have any key column between b and c, i will edit my post to share a sample data.

Comment: Do you have some small representative dataset? publish please if possible

Comment: @leftjoin thank you for your reponse, the dataset is in the question

Comment: @leftjoin did you have a chance to look at the data set?

Comment: @KoushikRoy any idea on how I can make this work? I am really stuck.

Comment: Yes. First I thought that self-join could be eliminated somehow using analytics functions, but looking on the dataset now I have no idea. For example for `A.16` in table b joined records from table `c` are A15, A18, A20, A 35. For A18 parents are A20, A35. It produces  huge duplication and I have no Idea now how the same can be achieved without join.

Comment: @leftjoin in fact I have to choose a single parent for each product with a condition on a variable named "counts" by taking the minimum. I will add that in the dataset

Comment: As @leftjoin said, its very difficult to avoid duplicates. Now, you can create partition on may be date1,date2. IF you have few date  values, you can partition on the combination of dates. Otherwise another route is bucketing.

Comment: @KoushikRoy like I said above to leftjoin , I want to keep a single parent for each product with a condition on a variable named "counts" by taking the minimum. I  added the field in the dataset

Comment: @leftjoin do you think i could acheive this with Lead or Lag functions ?